# How can I get Python's unittest to not catch exceptions?

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-unittest

I'm working on a Django project but I think this is a pure Python `unittest` question.

Normally, when you run tests, exceptions will be caught by the test runner and handled accordingly.

For debugging purposes, I want to disable this behavior, i.e. so that:

```
python -i manage.py test
```

will break into the interactive Python shell on an exception, as normal.

How to do that?

EDIT: based on the answers so far, it seems like this is more of a Django-specific question than I realized!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [django-nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose) test runner, it works with `unittest` tests, and run your tests like `python manage.py test -v2 --pdb`. And nose will run [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) for you.

Comment: Thanks. I've heard nose mentioned a lot with various benefits such as this, and it's on my to-do list to learn, but for now, I'm hoping there is a way to do this without it. Do you know if it's definitely not possible with the standard test runner?

Comment: It's not nice, but you can catch your exception in your code and run pdb.

Comment: FYI, I'm trying to figure out how to install django-nose, which looks great. It's giving me trouble so far... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215520/how-to-get-django-nose-installed-correctly

Comment: @Ghopper21, answered in your question

Comment: What if I want to just let it bubble up and be caught with PyCharm?  It doesn't allow use of pdb.

Comment: Apologies for only now accepting this answer. I never did get it working at the time. This morning I had another reason to use django-nose, and the installation worked on my current project (after a bit of fuss), so I was finally able to come back and test -- and accept -- your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

A new app [django-pdb](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-pdb#usage) makes this nicer, supporting a mode for breaking on test failures or uncaught exceptions in regular code.

Comment: +1, this works nicely with the new `manage.py test --pdb` flag. I'm now trying to get django-nose installed so I can compare the two approaches. (Btw, I'll keep using django-pdb anyhow for it's other debugging enhancements.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in a module within your package, then use `CondCatches(`*your exceptions,*`)` in your code:

```
# System Imports
import os

class NoSuchException(Exception):
    """ Null Exception will not match any exception."""
    pass

def CondCatches(conditional, *args):
    """
    Depending on conditional either returns the arguments or NoSuchException.

    Use this to check have a caught exception that is suppressed some of the
    time. e.g.:
    from DisableableExcept import CondCatches
    import os
    try:
        # Something like:
        print "Do something bad!"
        print 23/0
    except CondCatches(os.getenv('DEBUG'), Exception), e:
        #handle the exception in non DEBUG
        print 'Somthing has a problem!', e
    """
    if conditional:
        return (NoSuchException, )
    else:
        return args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Do SOMETHING if file is called on it's own.
    try:
        print 'To Suppress Catching this exception set DEBUG=anything'
        print 1 / 0
    except CondCatches(os.getenv('DEBUG'), ValueError, ZeroDivisionError), e:
        print "Caught Exception", e
```