# How to get django-nose installed correctly?

Tags: django, nose, django-nose

I'm having trouble getting django-nose running.

Per the [installation instructions](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose), I installed by:

1. Running `pip install django-nose`
2. Adding `'django_nose'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py (including at as the very last app, in case of possible app order issues)
3. Adding `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'` to settings.py

When I run a test i.e. `manage.py test`, I get:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no such table: django_content_type
```

I figured I need to sync the database. I am using South. When I use `manage.py syncdb`, `django_nose` doesn't show up in either the list of synced apps nor the list of "Not synced (use migrations)" apps.

Finally, when I try syncing with south anyhow, i.e. `manage.py schemamigration django_nose --initial`, I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: App with label django_nose is missing a models.py module.
```

I have Django 1.4 with South version 0.7.5 installed in a virtualenv.

What am I doing wrong? If nothing, how do I go about debugging this install problem?

Comment: I had the same problem. After running `nosetests` command from the project root,`django_nose` now works. It still does not show in the app list when running `./manage.py syncdb`, however. I have no idea why this works!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's an issue about apps ordering, a quote from django-nose manual:

> Using With South
>
> South installs its own test command that turns off migrations during testing. Make sure that   django-nose comes after south in INSTALLED_APPS so that django_nose's test command is used.

Comment: Afraid not. I suspected app order so I actually tried putting django_nose very last in `INSTALLED_APPS`, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the docs on github carefully, the problem is that when **south** is installed you need to put **django_nose** below **south**, [read more](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose#using-with-south).

So your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file should look something like below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
.....other apps...
....

south,
django_nose,
)
```

Comment: Hey thanks, but I did try this already, including with `django_nose` very last in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 0):

I too encountered similar issue while using kombu.transport.django in the INSTALLED_APPS. The error I got was "ImproperlyConfigured: App with label django is missing a models.py module.". Looks like the ordering of South does matter. What I did was to put **south** in the very bottom of the INSTALLED_APPS,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'djcelery',
'kombu.transport.django',
'sdm',
'cycletel_admin',
'django.contrib.admin',
'lettuce.django',
'south'
)
```

This helped resolve the issue. The migrations ran successfully. I used Django 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the apps you want to test into PROJECT_APPS in your settings; its trying to test django_nose and generate models for it when it doesn't have a models.py file.